# Is there a physical example where there are $N$ gapped degenerate ground states preserving $U(1)$ symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, ground-state

I am looking for systems (like QFTs, lattice models etc) where there are $N$ ground states which are all degenerate, and all are gapped, and preserving $U(1)$ global symmetry. For example, in certain choice of basis, each ground state is an eigenstate of $U(1)$, and different states have different charge.
$$g_{\alpha}|n\rangle = e^{i \alpha p_n}|n\rangle, ~~~ n=1, ..., N, ~~~~~ p_n\in \mathbb{Z}$$
Is there such an example ($N$ can be arbitrary as long as $N\neq 1$)? If not, is there a reason why this set-up is not physical?

Comment: What do you mean by "an eigenstate of U(1)"? The group has many possible representations, and any state is trivially an eigenstate of rotation by a phase

Comment: @catalogue_number Why would any state be an eigenstate?

Comment: What is a "gapped ground state"? Note that whenever you have symmetry breaking, the ground state manifold can still be spanned b ysymmetric states. (And also when you don't: You can *always* find a system of eigenstate which consists of symmetric states.)

Comment: @catalogue_number Sorry for the vague statement. I mean for example all of them can be an eigenstate. Question is updated.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Sorry for the vague statement. I mean for example all of them can be an eigenstate. Question is updated.

Comment: But this is *always* the case: for *any* symmetric Hamiltonian, you can choose a basis of the eigenstates (and thus of the ground states) where each eigenvector is symmetric (i.e. transforms as an irrep). I don't get your question.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I have this question because of the following reason: Let's assume N=2.  In such a system U(1) can not be spontaneously broken (SSB) because it only has two states (while SSB requires infinite states). So U(1) is not SSB. But if the two states are eigenstates of U(1) with different charges, one can always define two new states by linear combination, and the U(1) will rotate among the two new states. This seems a bit odd to me because on one hand U(1) is not SSB while on the other hand it rotates the two new states.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch therefore the question above aims to search for an example, which may help me to understand why there is no inconsistency between "U(1) is not SSB" and "U(1) rotates the two new states".

Comment: I don't understand what you say. Can you explain again? The linear combination will not be an eigenstate. That's why there is no SSB. It will only become an eigenstate in the limit N->infty, when the different low-energy states become degenerate.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thanks for the explanation. Let me first rephrase my question in the following way (which I think is more transparent): Suppose we have a Hamiltonian. In the infinite volume limit, it has N ground states, and there is a non vanishing gap above the ground states. Moreover the Hamiltonian has a U(1) symmetry. Since there are only finite number of ground states, U(1) can not be spontaneously broken. The question is whether can the ground states form nontrivial representation of U(1) provided that U(1) is not SSB.

Comment: Better. But I'm not sure what you mean by "form non-trivial representation". All U(1) representations are one-dimensional, so they behave pretty much the same. Or do you mean "Can the different ground states transform as *different* irreps."? And what is special about U(1)? Also discrete symmetries are usually not broken in a finite volume.

Comment: Right. I am not restricting to irreps. Here by trivial rep I mean every ground state is invariant under U(1) transformation, with all charge 0.

Comment: and by nontrivial representation, I mean the matrix is nontrivial: for example in the basis where all states are U(1) eigenstates, the matrix is just NxN diagonal matrix with n-th diagonal element e^{ialpha q_n} where q_n is the charge of n-th state. In particular I am interested in knowing if there are examples for which q_n\neq q_m where n\neq m. Other matrices can be obtained by conjugation by unitary matrices (i.e. basis transformation).